# RestKit - Data Mapping

Tags: objective-c, mapping, restkit, data-mapping

I'm new in RestKit.
 Can someone help me with mapping. I have JSON and I need to read  and save data from JSON. How I can do it?

```js
 {"data": {
    "viewer": {
      "themes": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "61c39",
              "name": "ff"
            }
          }
        {
            "node": {
              "id": "dd95af4b-"",
              "name": "growth",
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a part of my code for mapping:

```
// Defines mapping for DefaultThemes
RKEntityMapping *mappingDefaultTheme = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DefaultThemeData"
                                                         inManagedObjectStore:self.managedObjectStore];
mappingDefaultTheme.identificationAttributes = @[@"themeId"];
[mappingDefaultTheme addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"node.id" : @"themeId", @"node.name" : @"name"}];



RKResponseDescriptor *themeDefaultListResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mappingDefaultTheme
                                                                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                              pathPattern:@"graphql"
                                                                                                  keyPath:@"edges.node"
                                                                                              statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

I have error when I running the app:

```
Error: No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched.
```

So I need to know, how I should do data mapping?

Comment: You need to show the code you've tried and explain what it does wrong

Comment: I have added part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
RKObjectMapping* chartDataDetailMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MADefaultThemeData class]];

[chartDataDetailMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"themeId",
                                                             @"name": @"name"}];

RKObjectMapping* chartDataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MANode class]];
[chartDataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"edges":@"edges"}];

RKObjectMapping* alertInstanceMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MADefaultThemeList class]];

[alertInstanceMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"edges"
                                                                                     toKeyPath:@"edges"
                                                                                   withMapping:chartDataMapping]];

[chartDataMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"node"
                                                                                     toKeyPath:@"themeData"
                                                                                   withMapping:chartDataDetailMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:alertInstanceMapping
                                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                                        pathPattern:@"graphql"
                                                                                                        keyPath:@"data.viewer.themes"
                                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

[self addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

Answer (score 0):

The key path `data.viwer.themes.edges.node` is too deep because you're trying to drill down into an array and that isn't possible. The longest key path you can have is `data.viwer.themes.edges` and then the mapping will process each of the objects containing 'nodes'.

Comment: I updated the key path but I steel have the same error.

Comment: Looking at you update you didn't do what i said - you deleted the start of the key path instead of the end...

Comment: Well, then you're mapping themes, which you haven't given details for and for which your code uses keys that aren't in the json - how can i guess?

Comment: The questions is how I can read and save nodes from JSON? Yes, maybe I have made mistakes in code, that's why asking here!

Comment: Show the definition of `DefaultThemeData`

Comment: DefaultThemeData is entities with 2 attributes: name and themeId

Comment: And how does it relate to nodes - you need to give so much more information!

Comment: I request JSON data by this link http://popov.skyboxua.com/data.php
I need to create and save a list of node objects.
I created DefaultThemeData entity with 2 attributes: name and themeId
Then I created mapping(code in the begging of the post) but it's not working.

Comment: so the mapping sounds fine, just need to sort out the response descriptor and check the path pattern and key path. the path pattern looks like it should be `data.php`

Comment: ok, and how I can sort out the response descriptor and check the path pattern and key path? Could you help me with that?

Comment: my answer tells you the key path and my last comment tells you the path pattern

Comment: Sorry, I have missed about data.php

Comment: I just tried it and pathPattern:@"data.php" and I got a new error: "Expected status code in (400-499), got 200"

Comment: I don't understand about key path. What should be in key path?

Comment: how do you configure your base url then? `@"data.viwer.themes.edges"`